# Passing the Agent ID through popup Avaya one-x agent

Tags: popup, voip, tapi, avaya

I am using `Avaya one-x Agent 2.5`
and looking for passing the agent ID in addition to IVR data collected from the caller to a web-service in order to make popup screen.

Everything is working fine, but i don't know how to find the `Agent ID`.

Is the Agent ID registered anywhere in the onex-agent files ?

or can i use the `AES` to find out the ringing agent ?

any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this question is not a pure programming, but i think it is useful to share the solution here.

the Avaya One-x Agent application stores the agent ID in the settings file under the following path

> C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Avaya\one-X Agent\2.5\Profiles\default

line # 15

```
<Agent Login="6666" Password="" AutoLogin="false" Disabled="false" SavePassword="false" ReadOnly="false"
```

so, you can use the following code to store the Agent ID in a variable and use it for popup purposes.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Dim AgentID
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Avaya\one-X Agent\2.5\Profiles\default\Settings.xml", ForReading)

For i = 1 to 14
    objTextFile.ReadLine
Next

strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine
AgentID = mid(strLine, 19, 4)
msgbox (AgentID)
```

Regards